# How can I maintain proper URL navigation with React-Router-DOM and single-page scroll links in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using ReactJs with React-Router-DOM. I have a navbar with links such as "home," "about," "services," "portfolio," and "contact."

The "home" and "about" links are single-page scroll links, while "services," "portfolio," and "contact" are on different pages. I am using an anchor tag `<a>` instead of the `Link` tag from "react-router-dom" because the `Link` tag doesn't behave as expected for single-page scroll links.

Now, when I navigate from the "home" link to the "about" link, it changes the current URL from *domain* to *domain/#about*. Then, if I go from *domain/#about* to the "services" page, the current URL changes from *domain/#about* to *domain/services*.

---

## **Here's where my problem begins:**

if I am on any "services," "portfolio," or "contact" page and try to go back to the home and about pages, for example, when the current URL is *domain/services* and I click on the "about" link, the current URL changes from *domain/services* to *domain/services#about*. It doesn't go back to domain/#about; instead, it changes to domain/services#about.

## This is what I am doing on my Navbar component

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import "./css/navbar.css";
import Logo from "./Logo";

function Navbar(props) {
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(location);
  }, [location]);

  const singlePageScrollLinks = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a
            href="#home"
            className={`nav-link ${
              location.pathname === "/" && location.hash === "#home"
                ? "active"
                : ""
            }`}
          >
            Home
          </a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a
            href="#about"
            className={`nav-link ${
              location.pathname === "/" && location.hash === "#about"
                ? "active"
                : ""
            }`}
          >
            About
          </a>
        </li>
      </>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        position: "sticky",
        top: "-2px",
        backgroundColor: "#2c2c2c",
        zIndex: "2",
      }}
      id="nav-page"
    >
      <div className="d-flex justify-content-between list-unstyled top-nav">
        <li>+91 9876543210</li>
        <li>qwerty@mail.com</li>
      </div>
      <nav
        className="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary custom-nav"
        style={{ borderRadius: "45px 0 0 0" }}
      >
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/" style={{ width: "1px" }}>
            <Logo />
          </Link>
          <button
            className="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul className="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              {singlePageScrollLinks()}
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/services">
                  Services
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/portfolio">
                  Portfolio
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/contact">
                  Contact
                </Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: Use absolute link paths, e.g. target paths that start with `"/"` or use a library like [react-router-hash-link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link) to handle linking/navigation with URL hashes.

Answer (score 0):

Th problem in your navigation is you are just appending a hash. Your navbar code should be

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import "./css/navbar.css";
import Logo from "./Logo";

function Navbar(props) {
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(location);
  }, [location]);

  const singlePageScrollLinks = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a
            href="/#home"
            className={`nav-link ${
              location.pathname === "/" && location.hash === "#home"
                ? "active"
                : ""
            }`}
          >
            Home
          </a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a
            href="/#about"
            className={`nav-link ${
              location.pathname === "/" && location.hash === "#about"
                ? "active"
                : ""
            }`}
          >
            About
          </a>
        </li>
      </>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        position: "sticky",
        top: "-2px",
        backgroundColor: "#2c2c2c",
        zIndex: "2",
      }}
      id="nav-page"
    >
      <div className="d-flex justify-content-between list-unstyled top-nav">
        <li>+91 9876543210</li>
        <li>qwerty@mail.com</li>
      </div>
      <nav
        className="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary custom-nav"
        style={{ borderRadius: "45px 0 0 0" }}
      >
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/" style={{ width: "1px" }}>
            <Logo />
          </Link>
          <button
            className="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul className="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              {singlePageScrollLinks()}
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/services">
                  Services
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/portfolio">
                  Portfolio
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/contact">
                  Contact
                </Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

For scrolling you can use scrollIntoView but in a react way for better performance like this on your home page:

```
export default function Home() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const homeRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.hash) {
      scrollToEle(location.hash);
    }
  }, [location]);

  const scrollToEle = (id) => {
    const ele = homeRef.current.querySelector(`${id}`);
    if (ele) {
      ele.scrollIntoView({ behaviour: 'smooth' });
    }
  };
  return (
    <div ref={homeRef}>
      <div id="contact">Contact</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your link

from:

```
<a href="#home">Home</a>
<a href="#about">Home</a>
```

to this:

```
<a href="/#home">Home</a>
<a href="/#about">Home</a>
```

The issue is beacause you only added #tag instead of providing the path for the navigation. For ex: if you want to go to #about in home page you have to add "/" (the path for home) + "#about" (your hashtag)